# How to build a REST API in Laravel 4 and add users

Tags: api, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I am working with Laravel 4 attempting to build a REST API. I have to create a resourceful controller, model, and associated views for managing multiple api consumers. I want each api consumer to (at a minimum) have attributes for api_key and shared_secret. I have been reading Jeremy Kendall's page on Query Auth @ http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/13/api-query-authentication-with-query-auth/. I am getting very confused. I do not understand where everything should go.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a tutorial on user authentication: https://medium.com/on-coding/e8d93c9ce0e2

Here's one on ACL: https://medium.com/on-coding/a7f2fa1f9791

And here's one on REST API's in L4: https://medium.com/on-coding/c643022433ad

Comment: I have gone through the writeup (nice one) but i am still a little bit confused. Please check this link to help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114573/how-to-handle-user-registration-via-api-laravel

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to watch the [What’s New in Laravel 4 series](https://tutsplus.com/course/whats-new-in-laravel-4/) before doing any commando action.